# Multi language site with same content

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I want to make a site in 2 languages, but all the content will be absolutely the same (all posts will not be translated).
The only difference will be in things like theme messages (like 'Search', 'The page not found') that will be translated according to `WPLANG`. Also I have to have an ability to make some conditions in theme, according to `WPLANG`.
The multite solution is not good for me, as I don't want to copy all the post and taxonomies on two sites.
I thought to add a identification via URL (like `www.mysite.com/?lang=en`), to define `WPLANG` according to this, and store this variable in `session`, and, by this way, use it in theme.
But may be there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing it in a session would certainly be possible, but is not necessary at all.
Unless you're looking for a way to not include the query string in subsequently visited URLs. Here I'd rather go with a cookie than a session, since WP already relies on cookies and does not use sessions. But that's a matter of personal taste, I suppose.

Anyhow:
In your *wp-config.php*, you can define `WPLANG` conditionally like so (*wp-config.php* is loaded early, but other than that a normal php file like any other):

```
if ( isset( $_GET['lang'] ) ) {
    define( 'WPLANG', $_GET['lang'] );
} else {
    define( 'WPLANG', 'en_US' );
}
```

Or, if you'd like to use two-character identifiers for the query parameter and/or make it default to a certain language (here: English) if the parameter is invalid:

```
$language = isset( $_GET['lang'] ) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';
switch ( $language ) {
    case 'de':
        define( 'WPLANG', 'de_DE' );
    break;

    case 'en':
    default:
        define( 'WPLANG', 'en_US' );
}
```